# Prove that $7n^3-1$ can never be a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Prove that $7n^3-1$ can never be a perfect square.

hint: consider about congruences concepts.

I noticed that $7n^3$ is congruent to 6 mod 7 but I don't know if there is any definition or theorem about perfect square I can use in this question?

Comment: What are the possible values of a square number in mod $7$? Also in your explanation you meant to have written "$7n^3-1$ is congruent to..." not "$7n^3$ is congruent to..."

Comment: **Hint:** $$x\equiv r\pmod n\implies x^2\equiv r^2\pmod n$$

Comment: It could also be arranged to a Mordell equation. You can get more general similar results.

Comment: you are almost there! $7n^3-1\equiv 6\mod 7$ while perfect squares $n^2 \mod 7 $ can give just $1,4,2,2,4,1,0,\ldots$ that repeats cyclically and then is never $6$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it can be a square. Then there exist natural number $k$ such that $$7n^3=k^2+1$$

So $7|k^2+1$. There is a theorem that states that if $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $p|a^2+b^2$ that $p|a$ and $p|b$. So it is impossible.

Comment: If it is well known then why OP doesn't know about it? :-P.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Let us go through a list of squares numbers through modulo 7. It is a somewhat 'crude' method but it works nonetheless.

\begin{align}
1^2 &\equiv 1\pmod 7 \\
2^2 &\equiv 4\pmod 7 \\
3^2 &\equiv 2\pmod 7 \\
4^2 &\equiv 2\pmod 7 \\
5^2 &\equiv 4\pmod 7 \\
6^2 &\equiv 1\pmod 7 \\
7^2 &\equiv 0\pmod 7 \\
8^2 &\equiv 1\pmod 7 \\
9^2 &\equiv 4\pmod 7 \\
10^2 &\equiv 2\pmod 7 \\
11^2 &\equiv 2\pmod7\\
& \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\vdots
\end{align}

Notice that the pattern repeats every 7 terms. Also, notice that there is no number $n^2$ such that $n^2 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$.

You rightly found that $7n^3−1 \equiv 6\pmod 7$. That means $7n^3−1$ cannot equal $n^2$ for any $n \in \mathbb Z$.

$\therefore$ $7n^3−1$ is not a perfect square.

---

As for theorems on this topic, it is important to know the following:
$$a \equiv b \pmod m$$
$$\iff m|a-b$$

Furthermore, if $$a \equiv b \pmod m$$ and $$c \equiv d \pmod m$$

then the following theorems apply.

$$a \equiv c \pmod m$$
$$a+c\equiv b+d \pmod m$$
$$a \times c \equiv b \times d \pmod m$$